# What type of word is verlo?

Tags: definiciones

I see "verlo" in some sentences. But I don't understand what it is, is it a verb?

RAE's dictionary says that the word doesn't exist.

I see it translated as *looking* but it is nowhere to be found on ver's conjugation tables.

Is it a gerundio of some other verb or something? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

In Spanish pronouns can be "proclíticos" (placed before the verb) or "enclíticos" (added to the verb as suffixes).

"Verlo" is the result of adding the pronoun "lo" to the infinitive "ver". To say: *I want to see it/him*, you can say:

- Quiero ver**lo**.

or

- **Lo** quiero ver.

Both sentences mean the same thing.

With gerunds, it's just the same. To say: *I am seeing it/him*, you can say.

- Estoy viéndo**lo**.

or

- **Lo** estoy viendo.

With finite, that is, conjugated verbs (infinitive and gerund are non-finites), pronouns are always used before the verb and can only be found after the verb in past literature.

The only exception is the imperative, where pronouns are always found after the verb:

- Ve**lo**. (See it/him.)

Answer (score 1):

The word is *ver*, "to see".

*Verlo* is the infinitive of the verb with a masculine direct object pronoun *-lo*, "him; it".

When the verb is conjugated, the pronoun goes at the front of the verb.

*Lo veo* "I see him/it"

*Quiero verlo / Lo quiero ver* "I want to see him/it"